# How do I pass parameters to an asp.net function from an asp.net control inside an itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, repeater

I have a vote button in a repeater and I want to use it by giving the post id which is in the same itemtemplate in a repeater/datalist. I can't pass the value I get from Eval() to the codebehind function because it takes 2 arguments which are sender and eventargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `OnCommand` instead of `OnClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnVote" runat="server" Text="Vote" OnCommand="btnVote_Command" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Column1")%>' />
```

In the code-behind:

```
protected void btnVote_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    object column1 = e.CommandArgument;
}
```